# Over C, invertible operators have square roots?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, operator-theory

We know that on **finite-dimensional** vector spaces, **it is true**. This is 8.33 in Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*:

> Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space and $\, T\in L(V) \,$ is
> invertible. Then $T$  has a square root.

The question is that, if V is infinite-dimensional, does this result still hold?

I'd be much obliged if anyone could give a counterexample or prove that this result is true in general. Thanks!

Comment: If the vector space is the space of functions $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{C}$, and $T : (\ldots, x_{-2}, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) \mapsto (\ldots, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$, it's not immediately obvious what a square root of that operator would be.  (But it's also not immediately obvious that no square root exists at all.)

Comment: Although difficult for me, this counterexample looks nice. The important thing is that it tells us this result is wrong under infinite-dimensional conditions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful about the first example above. On the space $\ell^2$, the shift operator $T$ defined in the first comment above is a bounded invertible operator. Intuitively, a square root of $T$ should be a shift by one-half slot, which of course does not make sense. Thus one can easily believe that this invertible operator $T$ does not have a square root. However, this operator does have square root!! To see this, identify $\ell^2$ with $L^2$ of the unit circle and identify the shift with the operator of multiplication by $z$. Then the operator of multiplication by the square root of $z$ (choose any branch of the square root function) is a square root of $T$.

For an invertible operator that does not have a square root, consider the operator of multiplication by $z$ on the Hardy space of an annulus centered at the origin. This operator is invertible (its inverse is multiplication by $1/z$) but it does not have a square root.

Comment: Wow, Professor Axler, a big surprise to see you here! Thank you very much for the thoughtful answer!

Comment: +1 , although the second paragraph would be would be another Question for me.

Comment: See the paper "Square Roots of Operators" by Halmos and Lumer and Schaffer in Proceedings of the AMS 4 (1953), 142-149 for details about a class of invertible operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space that have no square root.